# select range and filter by prefix and then hide (issue with set range)

Tags: excel, vba, select, filter, hide

```
Sub Group()

     Dim arrList As Variant
     Dim rng As Excel.Range
     Dim rCell As Range
     Dim N As Long

Set rng = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
 
 arrList = Array("TP001P*")

For Each rCell In rng.Cells
For N = LBound(arrList) To UBound(arrList)

       If VBA.InStr(1, rCell.Value, arrList(N), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
       rCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Exit For
       End If
       Next 'N
       Next 'rCell
 
End Sub
```

Comment: remove the `.select`

Comment: Btw, the `.Cells` in `For Each rCell In rng.Cells` is redundant.

Comment: thank you, it now gives me problems here                                                                         If VBA.InStr(1, rCell.Value, arrList(N), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then                                           I changed it for                                                                                                                      If VBA.InStr(1, rCell.Value, arrList(N), "TP001P*") <> 1 Then                                                 with no success :(

Answer (score 1):

To filter "by prefix" use the Like function. Then by adding all the findings to a range, you hide the lines all together

```
Option Explicit

Sub Group()
   Dim arrList As Variant, rng As Range, rCell As Range, N As Long
   Dim lb As Long, ub As Long, toHide As Range
   Set rng = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
   arrList = Array("TP001P*")
   lb = LBound(arrList)
   ub = UBound(arrList)
   
   For Each rCell In rng.Cells
      For N = lb To ub
         If rCell.Value Like arrList(N) Then
            If toHide Is Nothing Then
               Set toHide = rCell
            Else
               Set toHide = Union(toHide, rCell)
            End If
            Exit For
         End If
      Next
   Next
   If Not toHide Is Nothing Then toHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

If you need the opposite results set a Not like this:

```
If Not (rCell.Value Like arrList(N)) Then
```

Since I don't seem to have understood what you need, I will supplement my answer with a more general solution to hide-show rows or columns with as many criteria as needed connected by OR.
[image]
Put this code in a module (not a sheet module):

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum ShowOrHide
   HideIt = True
   ShowIt = False
End Enum

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
'rngToScan: a rarge with one column OR one Row. If have one colum: hide-unhide rows, if have one row: hide-unhide columns
'withFoundsToDo: Choose what to do with the rows or columns that meet the criteria (Values: HideIt , ShowIt)
'caseSensitive: Set True for Case-sensitive comparison, otherwise set False
'arrCriteria(): Array with as many criteria as you need
'Usage examples:
'Call hide_Or_Show(Me.Range("A_NAMED_RANGE"),ShowIt,False,"OK*","GOOD*")
'Call hide_Or_Show(Me.Range("A10:A100"),ShowIt,False,"T4*","T5*","T6*","T*456")
'Call hide_Or_Show(Me.Range("A10:A100"),HideIt,False,"temp*","tmp*")
'Call hide_Or_Show(Me.Range("A10:A100"),HideIt,False,Range("A2").Value,Range("A3").Value,Range("A4").Value)
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Sub hide_Or_Show(rngToScan As Range, withFoundsToDo As ShowOrHide, caseSensitive As Boolean, ParamArray arrCriteria() As Variant)
   Dim rCell As Range, found As Range, notFound As Range, entireFound As Range, entireNotFound As Range
   Dim cc As Long, rr As Long, ub As Long, fbool As Boolean, nfbool As Boolean, critExist As Boolean, rslt As Boolean

   rr = rngToScan.Rows.CountLarge
   If (rr <> 1 And rngToScan.Columns.CountLarge <> 1) Then
      MsgBox ("Function hideOrShow> rngToScan must have one Row or one Column")
      Exit Sub
   End If
   ub = UBound(arrCriteria)
   For cc = 0 To ub
      If arrCriteria(cc) <> vbNullString Then
         critExist = True
         Exit For
      End If
   Next
   If Not critExist Then
      Set found = rngToScan
   Else
      For Each rCell In rngToScan.Cells
         For cc = 0 To ub
            If arrCriteria(cc) <> vbNullString Then
               If caseSensitive Then rslt = rCell.Value Like arrCriteria(cc) Else rslt = UCase(rCell.Value) Like UCase(arrCriteria(cc))
               If rslt Then
                  If found Is Nothing Then
                     Set found = rCell
                  Else
                     Set found = Union(found, rCell)
                  End If
                  GoTo LnextCell
               End If
            End If
         Next
         If notFound Is Nothing Then
            Set notFound = rCell
         Else
            Set notFound = Union(notFound, rCell)
         End If
LnextCell:
      Next
   End If
   fbool = Not found Is Nothing
   nfbool = Not notFound Is Nothing
   
   If rr = 1 Then 'show-hide columns
      If fbool Then Set entireFound = found.EntireColumn
      If nfbool Then Set entireNotFound = notFound.EntireColumn
   Else            'show-hide rows
      If fbool Then Set entireFound = found.EntireRow
      If nfbool Then Set entireNotFound = notFound.EntireRow
   End If

   If withFoundsToDo = HideIt Then     ' hide anything found, show anything not found  - in rngToScan
      If nfbool Then entireNotFound.Hidden = ShowIt
      If fbool Then entireFound.Hidden = HideIt
   Else                                'hide anything not found, show anything found  - in rngToScan
      If fbool Then entireFound.Hidden = ShowIt
      If nfbool Then entireNotFound.Hidden = HideIt
   End If
End Sub
```

Call hide_Or_Show from within the Sheet module. In my example I call it through Worksheet_Change where I check if any of the two criteria has changed and if it has indeed changed I call it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B12:B13")) Is Nothing Then
      Call hide_Or_Show(Me.Range("B3:B9"), ShowIt, False, Range("B12").Value, Range("B13").Value)
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does the opposite

Comment: "select range and filter by prefix and then hide"  Opposite of what?

Comment: It's hiding everything with the prefix

Comment: If you need any explanations, let me know. The new code added is for general use in any sheet, can hide/show rows or columns (depents from what range pass as parameter)