# Dynamic Rows Hide/Unhide through VBA on the basis of value selected from dropdown

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, dynamic-programming

I want a dynamic solution for below requirements:

**Requirement:** if a user select any value from the dropdown then it should make visible only those row which contains the same value in **column A** from user based selected dropdown value. and if user select "All" from drop down then it should show all tables/scenarios.

Also it will be good if drop down should be multiselect.

**>>For Example:** if user select "Cash" from dropdown then the code should process from row 5 including header and should make only visible Row5 to Row13.

**Note:** Row1 to Row4 shouldn't get effected by this process.

[image]

Comment: If you make the drop-down on another sheet, you could accomplish what you need with formulas (no VBA required). Would you be open to that?

Comment: @P.b, can you please elaborate how to achieve this with formula and also i want dropdown in same sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the code in the sheet's module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
      ' B2 is the cell with drop down list
      If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
         Call showIf(Target.Value2)
      End If
   End If
End Sub


Sub showIf(criteria As String)
   Dim colA As Range, found As Range, cnt As Long, frow As Long

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   ' maybe here you want to find the last non empty row
   ' but as i know excel reduces the actions in the usedRange
   Set colA = Me.Range("A:A")
   criteria = UCase(criteria)
   Err.Clear
   On Error GoTo Lerr
   If criteria <> "" And criteria <> "ALL" Then
      ' find the first row of criteria
      frow = WorksheetFunction.Match(criteria, colA, 0)
      ' count the rows witch meet the criteria
      cnt = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(colA, criteria)

      ' use union to add some rows on top, to be always visible
      Set found = Union(Range("A1:A2"), colA(frow).Resize(cnt, 1))
      
      ' hide all rows
      colA.EntireRow.Hidden = True
      
      ' show only rows meet the criteria Plus some in top
      found.EntireRow.Hidden = False
      
      ' select the cell with drop down menu
      Range("B2").Select
      ' scroll on top to see the unhidden rows
      ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
   Else
      colA.EntireRow.Hidden = False
      ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
   End If
   Exit Sub
Lerr:
   MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ")  " & Err.Source
   On Error GoTo 0
   ' if an error occurs show all rows
   colA.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: can we achive this with multiple selection also?

Comment: multiple selection of what ?

Comment: if user select multiple criteria at the same time like for eg. Cash and card. then how we can achieve this?

Comment: So yes, we can certainly have many criteria. I'm still waiting for you to tell me if you tried the code and if it does what you asked. I am here to learn and help others who want to learn. To close, I refer you to another answer of mine similar to your new question: the multiple criteria. There is no "ALL" but instead no criteria. The code is general purpose, see here the "hide_Or_Show": https://stackoverflow.com/a/76174755/15794828

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data sheet called `data` contain the following:
[image]

Then on a different sheet store a selection of unique transaction types for the dropdown selection including an option for selecting all values.

We can for instance use cell `H2` for the following formula:
`=VSTACK(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!A:A,data!A:A<>"")),"all")`

In this case that produces this spill:

[image]

In the drop down data validation that we store in `B2` we can refer to this spill range as `H2#`:

[image]

In `A6` (to F6) the headers are stored: `{"TYPE","TRANSACTION ID","DATE","PROD ID","STORE ID","TRANS_VALUE"}`

Then in `A7` we use the following formula:

```
=LET(a, FILTER(data!A:F,
                    IF(B2="all",
                          ISTEXT(data!A:A),
                          data!A:A=B2)),
     IFERROR(--a,a))
```

This formula filters the rows which equal the selection of your dropdown.
If `all` is selected, it filters any row where there's any text in column A of your data sheet.

[image]

you can choose to hide column H.

*I chose not to include the headers in the filter and have that hardcoded in the selection sheet. Otherwise, the way you set up the data it'll repeat the header for each type. You could accomplish that by not including a value in the header rows in your data, or to change the formula to:* `=LET(a,FILTER(data!A:F,IF(B2="all",ISNUMBER(data!C:C)),data!A:A=B2)),IFERROR(--a,a))`