Excel Repeating Array Dependent on Multi-Level Drop Down List
I am building a worksheet that has dependent lists. Once you select an item from the "Equipment" column, you then select an item from the "Equipment Action Needed" column. The selections available in the "Equipment Action Needed" column are dependent on the selection made in the "Equipment" column. The selection made in the "Equipment Action Needed" column should then produce an array of items in the next column labeled "Prep". The dependent drop down list works as intended and is not the problem. I have successfully  gotten the "Prep" column to produce one array. However, I cannot get the array to repeat. The goal is to select multiple items in the "Equipment Action Needed" column and have an entire prep list populate in the "Prep" column based off selected equipment. I am currently using an if statement that uses an IFERROR to produce the array. The IFERROR statement uses the index function and match function to produce the array. In the attached image, "Alignment" should produce a new array in the "Prep" column.
I've tried to make the "Prep" column dependent on the neighboring left cell. However, that only produces the first "Prep" item, not the entire prep list array for that "Equipment Action Needed". Also if the neighboring left cell is blank, I can't seem to make it reference the last non blank cell to proceed with the array. I've attempted to use VBA to achieve my results as well but have not made it very far. My VBA skills are limited to recording a macro and google searches. So the VBA program is a carbon copy of my original worksheet.
Screenshot With Data Tabs
"Equipment" Worksheet
"Prep" Worksheet

If you have Office 365 or 2021 you can make use of FILTER(). You need to create an actual spill range in your file somewhere and you can reference that spill range from your dropdown list. This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76500714/12634230

Thank you for the response @P.b I looked through the link you've attached, but I don't have 365 or 2021 so the FILTER() function is not an option.

It's hard to understand what data you're trying to fetch in which cases (I don't even think you show the data table where you fetch it from, only the current result). I think it would be helpful to post your data as markdown table(s).

@P.b thank you for bringing that up, my image wasn't very insightful. I've updated the image to include the worksheets at the bottom, as well as images of the two worksheets.

You could use CHOOSE:
=CHOOSE(XMATCH(A8,Table2[Equipment]),
        Table4[Agigator Job:],
        Table6[Bearing Job:],
        Table8[Coupling Job:])

The cell you keep this formula can be referenced as a spill range in your data validation list range A10# in example picture below:

This obviously did not list all options and the table names are unlikely to resemble, but I think this will help you adopt it to your situation.
